# Lithium Facebook Connect Error

Tags: php, facebook, lithium

I'm following the lithium facebook connect tutorial 
http://www.shift8creative.com/blog/facebook-connect-and-lithium

I get the following errors when i load my page

```
Notice: Undefined variable: html in /var/www/lithium/app/resources/tmp/cache/templates/template_views_signs_index.html_1175517_1299986110_1801.php on line 3`
```

and

`Fatal error: Call to a member function script() on a non-object in /var/www/lithium/app/resources/tmp/cache/templates/template_views_signs_index.html_1175517_1299986110_1801.php on line 3`

My Facebook.php page starts as follows

```
namespace facebook;
namespace \Exception;
```

And line 3 of my view

```
<?php $html->script('http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js', array('inline' => false)); ?>
```

What may the error stem out of?

Comment: I'm no lithium developer, but you did initialize `$html` right? and not just copy/pasted it as is?

Comment: Yes I did... Line 2 is `<?php $html=''; ?>` I still seem to get the same error. However if I put that declaration in line 3 right before `$html->script(...` the undefined variable notice goes away. If i initialize anywhere before in the document this should not happen right?  I'm still not sure about the second part of the error thought.

Comment: `$html = ''` makes `$html` an empty string, not an object.

Comment: ah, yes... recursion to convert to object ?

Comment: @Eva611: As I suspected, there should be a class in lithium that would initialize that variable, something like `$html = new LithiumHTMLClass();` or something (**P.S:** this is only an example!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`html` is the [HTML helper](http://lithify.me/docs/lithium/template/helper/Html%3a%3ascript%28%29) and isn't a magical variable anymore but can be reached using `$this->html` instead.

For more information, read the documentation about the [lithium helpers](http://lithify.me/docs/lithium/template)

So just do:

```
<?= $this->html->script('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js', /* … */) ?>
```